# How to add a timer for a specific method in java?

Tags: java, gwt

I want to execute a specific method which contains a service call. As it includes a service call , it will take some time for execution. I want to add a timer which will keep program in wait till that method completes its executiuon. Any work around for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "keep the program in wait"? What should happen if the timer expires?

Comment: further program execution depends on the result of service call.. so i want to wait for that result before further execution.

Comment: Well, why a timer then? What if the call takes too long?

Comment: Agree.. any other work around for this then?

Comment: The accepted answer will work for you with a timeout. If you don't want a timeout, just call `.get()`. For further information, look at the javadoc of `Future` and `FutureTask`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can organize an asynchroneous method execution with a timeout with `java.util.concurrent` package

```
    ExecutorService executorService = ...
    Object res = executorService.submit(new Callable<Object>() {
        public Object call() throws Exception {
            ... your logic
        }
    }).get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: Could be specified that `.submit()` actually returns a `Future` and that there is a `.get()` without a timeout too

Comment: i was trying this solution and even these classes (ExecutorService , futute etc) are not allowed on client side of GWT. There are restrictions on the use of classes on client side.    It gives error - No source code is available for type java.net.URL; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Comment: Well, ExecutorService and others are part of standard JRE since 1.5

Answer (score 1):

You can use a separate thread to call that service and using `join()` method of Thread class, you can force main program to wait until that thread finishes the execution.

Comment: I guess there are some limitations on the use of classes on client side in gwt and thread class is one of those (if i am not wrong). It gives error - No source code is available for type java.net.URL; did you forget to inherit a required module?.

Answer (score 0):

**Sheduler**

Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand(){

@Override

public void execute() {

// code here

}